# POCO C++ Getting only one notification when socket is readable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool, poco, reactor

I now writing game server and here is my onReadable function :

```
void CSConnection::onReadable(const AutoPtr<ReadableNotification>& pNf)
{
    try
    {
        char * rbuff = new char[128](); //allocate incoming packet memory
        int n = _socket.receiveBytes(rbuff, 128);
        if(n > 8)
        {
            WorkerThreadPool::getInstance().tp->start(*new LogicHandler(*this, rbuff));
        }
        else
        {
            delete rbuff;
            delete this;
        }
    }
    catch(Poco::Exception& exc)
    {
        app.logger().log(exc);
        delete this;
    }
}
```

I tried to move reading packet in thread pool's logic handler, but notification is called multiply.

Is there a way to get only one notification ?
Because reading in thread is slower and it calls 5-9 times onReadable.
Thanks.

Comment: You have a potential memory leak. If there's an exception then `rbuff` won't be deleted.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg rbuff is cleaned on thread pool task relase.